# Aggreageting rows in a data.frame by an assignment column

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have this example `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:10], a = sample(100,10), b = sample(100,10),
                 aggregate_with = c(rep(NA,6),"y","b","b","e"), aggregate_order = c(rep(NA,6),"a,b","a,b","b,a","a,b"))

> df
   id  a  b aggregate_with aggregate_order
1   a 27 21           <NA>            <NA>
2   b 37 18           <NA>            <NA>
3   c 57 68           <NA>            <NA>
4   d 89 38           <NA>            <NA>
5   e 20 74           <NA>            <NA>
6   f 86 48           <NA>            <NA>
7   g 97 98              y             a,b
8   h 62 93              b             a,b
9   i 58 35              b             b,a
10  j  6 71              e             a,b
```

I'd like to efficiently aggregate rows which their `aggregate_with` value matches `id` value of other rows (a row's own `aggregate_with` value cannot match it's own `id` value) and the function I'd like to apply is to sum their `a` and `b` values according to the assignment in the `aggregate_order` column. The `id`, `aggregate_with`, and `aggregate_order` of the aggregated rows should retain the values of the row indicated by the `aggregate_with` column.

Here's what the resulting `data.frame` should look like:

```
> aggregated.df
  id   a   b aggregate_with aggregate_order
1  a  27  21           <NA>            <NA>
2  b 134 169           <NA>            <NA>
3  c  57  68           <NA>            <NA>
4  d  89  38           <NA>            <NA>
5  e  26 145           <NA>            <NA>
6  f  86  48           <NA>            <NA>
7  g  97  98              y             a,b
```

As you can see, column `a` of row 2 in `aggregated.df` is the sum of columns `a`, `a`, and `b` of rows 2, 8, an 9 in `df`, respectively, and vice versa for column `b`. Columns `a` and `b` of row 5 in `aggregated.df` sum columns `a` and `b` of rows 5 and 10 of `df`. Although row 7 in `df` has an `aggregate_with` value, it's not present in `df` and therefore not aggregated.

Comment: looping - but thinking there's a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: You should edit with what you've got, so people don't spend a lot of effort getting to where you already are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `data.table` library.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

#a table to join with
dt2 <- dt[, list(id = aggregate_with, a, b, aggregate_order)]
#set the right order
dt2[, c('a', 'b') := list(ifelse(aggregate_order == 'a,b', a, b), ifelse(aggregate_order == 'a,b', b, a))]
setkey(dt2, id)

#joining tables
res <- dt2[dt]

#replacing NA's with 0 and summing
for (j in c('a', 'b')) set(res, which(is.na(res[[j]])), j, 0)
res[!aggregate_with %in% id, list(a = sum(a) + i.a[1], b = sum(b) + i.b[1]), by = id]
```